# How to add function as Value in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have another .py file where all functions are written, e.g.

```
def EqualToCheck(value, comparingValue, ExpectedVal:bool):
    if (value == comparingValue):
        return ExpectedVal
    else :
        return not ExpectedVal

def LessThanCheck(value, comparingValue, ExpectedVal:bool):
    if (value < comparingValue):
        return ExpectedVal
    else :
        return not ExpectedVal
```

I want to call these functions from another py file where I want to call these functions if my data has a certain string. e.g.

```
callFunc = {
 "checkEqual" : EqualToCheck(value, comparingValue, ExpectedVal),
 "lessthanEqual" : LessThanCheck(value, comparingValue, ExpectedVal)
}
```

I have already imported the py file, i.e. I'm able to access these functions, but I need to use these functions as a value for a dictionary.

so that I can call it something like this

```
if a == "checkEqual":
   callFunc['checkEqual'](5,6,True)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: use an import statement

Comment: ahh! Perhaps I didn't phrase my question right. I have already imported the py file, i.e. I'm able to access these functions, but I need to use these functions as a value for a dictionary

Comment: So what exactly isn't working? Your example is incomplete, but valid, assuming the omitted parts are also valid.

Comment: Edited again, hope this helps

Comment: The `callFunc` dictionary is calling the equality functions _when it is defined_, but that's probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functions themselves in the dict definition, without calling them:

```
callFunc = {
 "checkEqual": EqualToCheck,
 "lessthanEqual": LessThanCheck,
}
```

In Python, functions are first-class objects which live in the same namespaces as any other type of variables. A function definition creates a variable binding just like an assignment. You can use these variables in expressions like any other data type.

```
if a == "checkEqual":
   callFunc['checkEqual'](5,6,True)
```